# React-Native-Mapbox-GL fails to link

Tags: react-native, linker, cocoapods, mapbox-gl, react-native-ios

When reproducing step by step this [this original example](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) of `RCTMapboxGL (5.1.0)` I run into an error with the linker. This happens to me every time I try to use `RCTMapboxGL`.

I tried both the:

- [Manual installation process for iOS](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/ios/install.md)

Xcode console:

[image: Duplicate definition]

- [Installation process with CocoaPods](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/ios/install-cocoapods.md)

Xcode console:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTMapboxAnnotation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRCTMapboxGL.a(RCTMapboxGL.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The missing symbol `RCTMapboxAnnotation` is in `../node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/ios/RCTMapboxGL.xcodeproj`, which is already added to my project as a reference.

[image: RCTMapboxAnnotation]

Other Linker Flags in Xcode Build Settings

[image: Other Linker Flags in Xcode Build Settings]

Answer (score 1):

My solution was fixing all React import statements across the MapboxGL library.

Turning them into global imports in the form `#import <React/MissingClass.h>` solved the problem:

e.g. `#import RCTView.h` to `#import <React/RCTView.h>`

**(9 files in total):**

`RCTMapboxAnnotation.m`:

```
#import "RCTMapboxAnnotation.h"
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/UIView+React.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
```

`RCTMapboxAnnotation.h`:

```
#import "RCTMapboxAnnotation.h"
#import <MapBox/MapBox.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert+MapKit.h>
#import <React/RCTComponent.h>
#import "RCTMapboxGL.h"
```

`RCTMapboxAnnotationManager.m`:

```
#import "RCTMapboxAnnotationManager.h"
#import <React/RCTUIManager.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert+CoreLocation.h>
#import <React/UIView+React.h>
#import "RCTMapboxAnnotation.h"
```

`RCTMapboxAnnotationManager.h`:

```
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
```

`RCTMapboxGL.h`:

```
#import <Mapbox/Mapbox.h>
#import <React/RCTView.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

`RCTMapboxGL.m`:

```
#import "RCTMapboxGL.h"
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/UIView+React.h>
#import <React/RCTLog.h>
#import "RCTMapboxGLConversions.h"
#import "RCTMapboxAnnotation.h"
```

`RCTMapboxGLManager.h`:

```
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>
```

`RCTMapboxGLManager.m`:

```
#import "RCTMapboxGLManager.h"
#import "RCTMapboxGL.h"
#import <Mapbox/Mapbox.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert+CoreLocation.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert+MapKit.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/UIView+React.h>
#import <React/RCTUIManager.h>
#import "RCTMapboxGLConversions.h"
#import "MGLPolygon+RCTAdditions.h"
#import "MGLPolyline+RCTAdditions.h"
```

`RCTMapboxGLConversions.m`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert+CoreLocation.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert+MapKit.h>
#import "RCTMapboxGL.h"
```

Comment: This worked for me along with fixing the linking Framework Search Path referenced in this git issue comment: https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/297#issuecomment-247644647